# Delete all files of the form x.y when a file x.z exists

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to delete all files named *foo*.o, only if a corresponding *foo*.asm file exists, for all *foo*.

I could do it with a `for` loop something like this:

```sh
for asmfile in *.asm; do
    prefix=${asmfile%".asm"}
    echo "Processing $asmfile ($prefix)"
    rm -f "${prefix}.o"
done
```

... but is there something less awkward or more idiomatic in bash?

Comment: Your example looks fine to me. I am not sure what is awkward about it.

Comment: Only thing  I cant think of is if you have some problematic file names that starts with a `dash` `-` . `rm` will complain other than that your code seems to be valid even for `posix` `sh` shells.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to obtain the prefix:

```
 PREFIX=`basename $ASMFILE .asm`
```